# Windows service with WCF returning wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

Okay, so I do not have any code for this problem, as it is currently residing at work. This is a problem I experienced today.

My setup:

I have a `Windows Service` and a client application. The client connects to and communicates with the service via a `wsHttpBinding`. One of the methods of the service calls a custom class I created for downloading and mapping `XML` to `POCO`. It then returns a list of these to the client application.

The problem:

When the service uses the custom class, the empty list is returned to the client. When the code is moved from the custom class, directly into the service method, then it returns a populated list. The code that is moved is exactly the same.

I've tested the custom class separately and it works! So this must be some weird side-effect from running in a service rather than an application.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided the code, and you have not mentioned what sort of application it is that you are working on,  its hard to tell what is causing the issue.I am assuming that you are working on ajax calls of a web application and sharing the way I debug in this particular scenario.
Just right below the statement

*[OperationContract]* 
write the following statement

*[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]*

and in the client location just use a alert box and alert the response using

*JSON.stringify(response)*
 in this case response is the the ajax response client has received.In the alert message the object type with its namespace and class directory in the attribute __type so you can see the structure and see what is causing the issue.